# How to read Unsigned integer from binary file?

Tags: python

How to read "Unsigned 8/16/24/32/64-bit integer" from binary file ?
( big-endian byte order )
unpack ?
any examples ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read info from binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761461/how-to-read-info-from-binary-file)

Comment: more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163459/reading-integers-from-binary-file-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module. That covers 8,16,32 and 64 bits. 24 bits you will need to do some extra fiddling yourself

Examples are [here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#examples)

Comment: Can you give an example for converting (2) 12-bit data stored in 3 in-order bytes into 2 ints? These are stored in a binary file.